# Prepending git commit message without making a new line

Tags: git, githooks

I am using this one liner in `prepare-commit-msg` hook to prepend the commit message with a custom string:

```
echo "text " | cat - $COMMIT_MSG_FILE > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
```

Unfortunately, every commit message contins "text" followed by CRLF and the rest of the commit message on the next line. For example, if commit message is: `"Commit 123"`, the new commit message would be

```
"text
Commit 123"
```

and not `"textCommit 123"`, which is what I want.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

Don't pipe your echo statement to cat. Instead use command substitution of the cat statement in your echo string:

```
echo "text $(cat $COMMIT_MSG_FILE)" > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

`echo` prints a newline.  Use a command that does not: this might be `echo -n`, depending on your `echo` vintage, or `printf`, if you have it, will do:

```
echo -n "text " | cat - $COMMIT_MSG_FILE > /tmp/out && mv /tmp/out $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
```

[dGot14U's method using command substitution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534712/1256452) also works.  Consider as well using in-place `sed`:

```
sed -i '' '1s/^/text /' $COMMIT_MSG_FILE
```

Whether and when `-i` needs a separate empty-string argument `''`, as shown here, is OS-dependent: MacOS `sed` demands one, Linux `sed` forbids one.  I have used this in scripts:

```
if sed --version >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # apparently this is gnu sed, so -i requires the extension attached
    sedinplace="-i"
else
    # apparently this is BSD/MacOS sed, so -i requires a separate argument
    sedinplace="-i ''"
fi
# ...
sed $sedinplace -e cmd1 -e cmd2 $file
```

The `$sedinplace` then expands to the right thing.